# Pattern for Hierarchical data retrieval and displaying using Asynchronous calls?

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, asynchronous, design-patterns, hierarchical-data

Context Silverlight/WPF, C#, .NET 4,

I have a 4 level deep tree of thumbnails I need to enumerate and display in some meaningful way.
 For a Synchronous execution (sequential world) we could think like the following:

```
    Channels = Channels_Build("CHANNELS.XML");
    foreach Ch in Channels
    {
         Cats = Cats_Build( Ch.URL ) ;
         foreach Cat in Cats
         {
             PLs = PLs_Build( Cat.URL ) ;
             foreach PL in PLs
             {
                  Medias = Medias_Build( PL.URL ) ;
                  foreach Media in Medias 
                              display Media image
             }
       }
 }
```

.
However I have an Async loading model for XML, images, ..., so I am thinking something like this:

```
Channels_Build("CHANNELS.XML");
Channels_Loaded()
{   // Channels build from some returned XML
    foreach Ch in Channels
        Cats_Build( Ch.URL, ??? ) ;   //async calls
}
Cats_Loaded()
{   // Cats build from some returned XML
    foreach Cat in Cats
        PLs_Build( Cat.URL ... ) ;
}
PLs_Loaded()
{   // PLs build from some returned XML
    foreach PL in PLs
        MediaList_Build( PL.URL ... ) ; 
}
MediaList_Loaded()
{   // MediaList build from some returned XML
    foreach media in MediaList
        display Media image 
}
```

Each of Channels_Build, Cats_Build, PLs_Build,  MediaList_Build make an Async call and thus have an associated callback xxx_Loaded()

Each Channel has 1 or more Categories. 
Each Category has 1 or more PlayLists.
Each PlayList has 1 or more Media
Thus, I have a 4 levels deep hierarchical structure

You can assume Channels, Cats, PLs and MediaList share a common base class.

Should I fold this 4x logic into a single recursive build method? How?   I would have to make the build process pass some info (parent node) to its corresponding callback   (I looked up IAsyncResult.AsyncState)

My brain is locked up and I can't think of what's needed here?  recursion?, passing info to Async calls, specific pattern?, ...

Should I build the tree data in memory, into one structure, first? or would that be useful only if I decide to use a TreeView control?  What if I decide to display the info using a repeating template into a listbox for example. The template would display:

```
Channel-Image+Name
        Category-Image+Name
                PlayList-Image+Name
                        MediaList images...
```

Yes, the non-leaf nodes would repeat visually down the list.  That's fine as it might provide the map I am looking for.

So the puzzling question remains:
How do I go about **enumerating and displaying** all the nodes in this Async model?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at Async CTP refresh that simplifies this stuff a lot